# Was there an official campaign button printed and circulated with the DeSantis name and the likenesses of both Ron DeSantis and Ronald Reagan?

Tags: campaigning, symbols, republican-primary

The lead in to the [PBS NewsHour full episode, June 16, 2023](https://youtu.be/m0h30LNKrAg?t=23) includes

> ...plus we speak with Miami mayor Francis Suarez about why he's joining the already crowded field of republican presidential candidates.

and on the screen is a graphic depicting a large collection of what look like they could be recent [campaign buttons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Campaign_button). There are several showing what look like the faces of [Nikki Haley](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nikki_Haley), [Mike Pence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mike_Pence), [Tim Scott](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tim_Scott), [Donald Trump](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donald_Trump) and [Ron DeSantis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ron_DeSantis), but there are some buttons that show pairs of people and it's too early for the tickets to include vide president, and at the bottom left there's a button with the upper half of the face covered and the name appears to be something like "____R Carlson".

My focus is on one button shown somewhat out of focus (or perhaps "bokehed") that appears to have the words "DeSantis" and "Governor" on it with two overlapping faces shown as if they are standing roughly shoulder-to-shoulder.

To me and my mildly prosopagnosian brain, it looks a lot like Ronald Reagan in the front and Ron DeSantis in the back, which if true (if this was really printed and circulated) would be... interesting.

(though it also can look like [Phil Hartman *playing* Ronald Regan](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/101457/45856) or Fox News's chief political anchor and executive editor [Bret Baier](https://www.foxnews.com/person/b/bret-baier))

**Question:** Was there an official campaign button printed and circulated with the DeSantis name and the likenesses of both Ron DeSantis and Ronald Reagan? *If so,* which campaign, what did the button say exactly (I can't read it), and were there contemporaneous slogans referring to the pair?

---

[image: screenshot from the PBS NewsHour full episode, June 16, 2023 https://youtu.be/m0h30LNKrAg?t=23]

**above:** screenshot from the video. **below:** shameless, unrpofessional attempt to sharpen the blurred image somewhat

[image: shameless, unrpofessional attempt to sharpen the blurred, cropped screenshot from the PBS NewsHour full episode, June 16, 2023 https://youtu.be/m0h30LNKrAg?t=23]

Comment: Not really a good fit for this forum. vote to close

Comment: @TedWrigley Stack Exchange isn't a forum. What is it about asking about the possibility that DeSantis used an image of him and Reagan standing shoulder-to-shoulder and for any  contemporaneous campaign slogans referring to the pair that isn't centrally on-topic here in Politics SE? Can you articulate that so that I might better address your concern?

Comment: Excellent use of this not forum. Vote to Leave Open.

Comment: Anyone can make a badge:  note the top left is a blank template with silhouette and "Your Title /  Slogan",  and at the bottom right is some badge with Trump and Cannabis.  There is at least one "Trump/DeSantis Dream Team" badge.    So given that the Reagan is a Republican superstar, and supporters of DeSantis would want him to be associated with Reagan... is there any surprise that someone has made a badge with Reagan and DeSantis photoshopped together?  The slogan seems to be "Draft Desantis",  suggesting this badge was produced before he announced his campaign.

Comment: @JamesK Thanks for the help with the blurred writing! Ya the photo indicates that it's plausible but only enough so to look (and therefore ask) further. "official campaign badges" can be verified by finding them on sale on the candidate's own merchandise website (several candidates likely have those) or finding a photo with the candidate or a campaign staff member displaying one, and citing a "contemporaneous campaign slogan" from the candidate's campaign (which I've also asked for) would work together with that to form a fact-based answer. Let's see what fact-based answers may arise.

Comment: By the way, it's "Tucker Carlson"... I've had a search with the usual tools, and can't find that badge. Others may do better.

Comment: @JamesK yes, I wasn't going to say it, but it certainly seems the most likely "____R Carlson" I pointed that one out to help highlight the diversity present - some are clearly candidates, but this  "____R Carlson" individual certainly isn't at the moment!

Comment: Voting not to close - This question can be answered factually.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While it's hard to prove a negative, it seems unlikely that this is an "official campaign" product.

The text on the badge seems to read "Draft Gov Ron DeSantis 2024". This is a message that a support group would make prior to the start the official campaign.  It means "Make DeSantis Run". Hence when this badge was made, the DaSantis campaign had not yet begun.

The image on the badge certainly seems to be Reagan.  This is not so unlikely as Reagan is a Republican super-star, and supporters of DeSantis would want their preferred candidate to be associated with Reagan.

Also (as per the comment below) Both are named "Ronald".  I think the slogan above is "One Ron to Another".  This would fit with the message that DeSantis is the heir to the policies of Reagan.  However, De Santis has not used this slogan on his website in other publicity. This again suggests an unofficial product.

Many of the other badges are also not "Offical".  I see a "Tucker Carson '24" badge, a "Trump on Drugs" badge, A "Trump-DeSantis joint campaign" badge and a template "Insert portrait here" badge. None of these are associated with an official campaign.

Comment: Also stating the obvious: They're both named Ronald.

Comment: Yes!  of course!  I think I can make out the slogan above the picture now.

Comment: I'll vote for "Insert portrait here" over any of the others. :)